# Working with PDF Forms and PDFTK & PHP

Tags: php, pdftk

I have a PDF that I am using PDFTK to rip the fields out of. My problem is that the order of the fields and field names are not very clear in the field dump. For example: Checkboxes are given field name "box7", "box3", "box2". I do not know which checkboxes these are without testing.

I need to be able to pro grammatically identify these fields. Or I need to know their location on the pdf.

Ultimately, how can I properly identify these fields either through the user clicking on the field they want or pro grammatically?

Answer (score 0):

Open your pdf in Adobe LiveCycle form designer (included with paid versions of acrobat from version 7 and up). You can see the form field names, rename them as needed etc... LiveCycle blows acrobat forms out of the water! I use PDFTK/PHP/LiveCycle PDFs my work to run our entire product labeling system and created a document self service portal for customers on our website.... feel free to follow up with more questions if you get stuck